# Decode in qliksense expression

Tags: decode, qliksense

There is decode function in my expression and I convert this decode in qliksense expression .. and it looks like qliksense don't have keyword of decode by default

So how I convert this decode in qliksense

```
SUM(DECODE(Rcount,0,DECODE(H.documentno,NULL,(C.gross- C.amont),0),0))
```

Any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent of `Decode` in Qlik is the [if .. then .. else](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/February2021/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ScriptControlStatements/If.htm) statement.

Your statement can be converted to:

```sql
SUM(
  if( Rcount = 0,
    if( isNull(H.documentno), C.gross - C.amont, 0) 
    ,0)
)
```

If we start with the inner `Decode`

> `DECODE(H.documentno,NULL,(C.gross- C.amont),0)`

It can be "translated" to: If `H.documentno` is `Null` then return `C.gross- C.amont` else return `0`

And the outer `Decode` can be translated to: if `Rcount` is `0` then return the inner `Decode` statement else return `0`

Bit of an warning/advice. In general `if .. then .. else` statements can be slow(er) in expressions. You might not see the difference in small datasets but in big/large ones its visible. If you **can** move this calculation in the load script and in the frontend just `Sum()` the result then the frontend calculation will be faster

Comment: hello thanks for answer . want to ask is it possible to do that with  pick and wildmatch ?

Comment: Cant tell. It depends on your dataset.

Comment: ok will you please tell me about this one .. SUM(DECODE(RLCOUNT,0,DECODE(DOCUMENTNO,NULL,0,(GROSS- AMOUNT)),(GROSS - AMOUNT)))

Comment: something like this: `SUM(
  if(RLCOUNT = 0,
    if(isNull(DOCUMENTNO),0,(GROSS- AMOUNT)),
    (GROSS - AMOUNT))
)`

Comment: this shows an error.. error is error in expression :it takes 2-3 parameters @Stefan Stoichev

Comment: `SUM(   if(RLCOUNT = 0,     if(isNull(DOCUMENTNO),0,(GROSS- AMOUNT)),     (GROSS - AMOUNT)), 0 )`

Comment: Hello .. KIndly check my updated question @Stefan Stoichev

Comment: will you please reply @Stefan Stoichev